# Enable PDF download from URL using htpasswd (APACHE and WP)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have a website with an UPLOAD folder full of PDF files.

Directory list is disabled but Im not able to enable password to download file

Assuming that the directory abs path is /home/user/server/wp-content/ninja-upload/11/

Ive created in that path 2 files

**.htpasswd**

```
admin:qwe3f43?r4
```

**.htaccess**

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<Files ~ "\.(pdf)$">
Deny from all
AuthName "Admins Only"
AuthUserFile /home/user/server/wp-content/ninja-upload/11/.htpasswd
AuthType basic
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Didnt works.
Ive made a lot of try but any success: when i use direct link

```
http://website/wp-content/ninja-upload/11/a.pdf
```

I can read it without asking any pass

EDIT: i'm using siteground as hosting. Is it possible that siteground use diferent tool? because has a protection directory tool (but i need to use htaccess because i need to populate dinamically the htpasswd file each user registration on WP)